# Asymptotic regression in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, curve-fitting, modeling

I have [this](https://pastebin.com/A3s9dUKp) portion of a data-set, where the `y` values eventually must reach an asymptotic limit. Here is a plot of the first 300 entries:

[image: Asymptotic tendency of data-set]

I have seen [`asymptotic regression`](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/curve-fitting-with-linear-and-nonlinear-regression) (of the form `y = b0 + b1*(1-exp(-exp(lrc) * x)`) and I think it would be the best model to fit this data. R seemingly already has the [function](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/NLSstAsymptotic.html) in its libraries, but I cannot find one in **Python**.

(1) Is there any library function for asymptotic regression or relevant saturation dynamics models as answered by Cleb below? If not, how to model it using scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

(2) Also how to predict the maximum integer value of the curve? Example, If `y=2454.1234` is the value at `X=10**20` and `y=2545.5678` at `X=10**50`, for a certain model, I want to obtain `2454`. Is there any one-shot way, other than linear search?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily fit it using [scipy's curve_fit function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). I used a different model but you can easily change that.

The output you get looks as follows:

[image]

This is the code which is quite self-explanatory:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def f(x, a, b, n):
    return a * x ** n  / (x ** n + b)


data = pd.read_csv('data.txt.txt', sep='\t')

y = data['y'].astype(float)
x = data['X'].astype(float)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[1800., 20., 1.])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), 'r-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the model you have used?

Comment: @Ain: Just a model one can use to describe saturation dynamics. You can replace it by your desired model, but then initial conditions (`p0`) will be important; you would probably have to fit the logarithm of the model.

Comment: How to do that? Could you add how to select the p0 values in your answer? That would be a great help.

Comment: @Ain: Not much time now, might be able to do it later on. Usually I plot the data and the output of the function for some parameters values to get at least the shape correct; the rest `curve_fit` will do :).

Comment: Sure, @Cleb I look forward to it. Thanks!

Comment: can you share how you derived the p0? Thanks

Comment: @Ain: Sorry, completely forgot about this... In this model, `a` is the maximum of the curve, your data seem to saturate around there, so it seemed to be a good choice. For `n=1`, `x=b` is the value where you reach `a/2`, so `20`, was a good choice. The `1` for `n` was just picked "randomly".